# Skin class is not getting initialized when I expect it to

Tags: apache-flex, skin

Suppose that I have a chunk of code like this:

```
var myPopup:MyPopup = new MyPopup();    
myPopup.mainModel = model;      
PopUpManager.addPopUp(myPopup,this);
```

The beginning of `MyPopup` looks like this:

```
<views:BlaBla 
    ...
    skinClass="com.mySkinClass" 
    ...
    >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            [SkinPart] public var aButton:Button;

            public function set mainModel(mainModel:Something):void {
                ...
                aButton.addEventListener(...);
                ...
            }
```

The mainModel setter references the aButton variable that is initialized in the skin.  Oddly enough the skin is not initialized until *after* the the setter has run.  This causes a null pointer exception.  I expect the skin to be initialized in the `var myPopup:MyPopup = new MyPopup();` line.  Why is this not the case?  Is there a way that I can force the skin to be initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question: the skin is not created until until the Object is added to the stage.  This means that you either have to do this:

#### Option 1

```
var myPopup:MyPopup = new MyPopup();    
PopUpManager.addPopUp(myPopup,this);  
myPopup.mainModel = model;
```

or

#### Option 2

```
var myPopup:MyPopup = new MyPopup();  
myPopup.mainModel = model;   
PopUpManager.addPopUp(myPopup,this);
```

But move all references to objects created in the skin from the setter for mainModel and into a method triggered by `creationComplete`.

Comment: You should actually do it by overriding partAdded in your skinnable component.

Comment: @Jonathan Why?  Completion complete works.  Is it possible I will having timing issues?  Source?

Comment: because why bother adding another event listener when the built in partAdded function works great for this exact purpose and that's why it exists in the first place. The Flex 4.5 docs have all the information on writing skinnable components.